# nodejs express mongoose connect to db error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I use nodejs express and mongoose to connect mongodb,I've created a config.js in root folder.I am trying to exports db connect in db.js and trying to import in adminController.js

But when I run the server and refresh the browser ,it log me some errors and not log my log in  terminal.

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    cookieScret:'ThreeKingdoms',
    db:'threekingdoms',
    host:'localhost',
    port:27017
}
```

**db.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        config = require('../config'),
        connection = mongoose.connection;


    module.exports = function(mongoose){
        return mongoose.connect('mongodb://'+config.host+'/'+config.db);
    }
```

**adminController.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        mainInfo = require('../models/admin'),
        db = require('../models/db');

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('admin', { title: 'hey im here!how are you' });
        db.on('error',console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.once('open', function() {
            console.log(db)
        });
        console.log(db)
    });

    router.post('/',function(req,res,next){
        //console.log(req.body)
        var mainInfo = mongoose.model('mainInfo');
    })

    module.exports = router;
```

[question files is in red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhmbM.jpg)
[terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6b58.jpg)

I am new to nodejs,so please help me,Thanks

Comment: can you say what browser logs?

Comment: did you run the command "node app.js" in terminal?

Comment: logs are in teminal,i use chrome to check my web

Comment: yes ,check this http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6b58.jpg

Comment: Please add admin part

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that you don't have kerberos installed. Please run npm install kerberos.
Also, the line

```
Can't set headers after they're sent
```

Suggests you're trying to modify/send the response after it was already sent back to the client, and that's the error you're getting.

Comment: i already have kerberos in my node_modules folder i need to require it in my file?and seems if i trying to open a db connect,terminal will show me the 'Can't set headers after they're sent'..... error

Comment: is kerberos needs python?when i npm install kerberos ,terminal log me some errors

> kerberos@0.0.18 install E:\bennu\ThreeKingdoms\node_modules\kerber
os
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)


E:\bennu\ThreeKingdoms\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_conf
ig_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node
-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  el
se (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can
 set the PYTHON env variable.

Answer (score 0):

finally it is work now,but it doesn't matter with 'kerberos' ,it is i use wrong way to export my module.terminal still log me 'kerberos undefined' but web can work,i think maybe some time i will try to figure this question out.thanks for your attention